# Possible JavaFX Canvas Bug when rendering lots of paths?

Tags: canvas, javafx

I am trying to do some GIS work. I need to be able to render lots of information (1.3M triangles, for example, plus graphics rendered inside each one). I tested retained mode graphics under JavaFX but it doesn't perform well enough at this scale, so I tried canvas.

The code below creates a flat icosahedron (20 sided figure) and recursively subdivides it into smaller and smaller triangles.

At levels of recursion 0 to 4 (Line 36 of GIS.java), everything works great. Once I go to 5 or more, though, I start to see very strange canvas rendering. The figure is rendered far to the right of the y-axis (x=0 for the leftmost triangles) and appears to overwrite itself in big sections.

I transliterated this code to .Net and it works perfectly (as it does in Java at recursions 0 to 4) so I don't believe it's a logic/algorithm problem.

Apologies in advance for the length of the code. I stripped out everything I could, but it still has a fair amount of code.

There are two files - GIS.java that is the main form, and HexGrid.java which is the class that creates the grid and renders it onto a canvas.

One more interesting note: lines 98 to 105 of HexGrid.java draw red lines to show the x- and y- axes. I was trying to see where the canvas thought the axes were since the rendering was far out of expected place. If you uncomment the gc.stroke() on line 105 with recursion 4 or higher, that also blows up canvas and the rendering is FAR different than expected.  At recursions of 3 or lower, everything performs as expected.

I hope I'm just doing something wrong! I'm really hoping to stick with JavaFX for this project.

Thanks in advance.

********** GIS.java *******************

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class GIS extends Application{
    Pane drawPane;


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        Scene primaryScene = new Scene(root, 900, 800);
        primaryStage.setScene(primaryScene);
        primaryStage.setWidth(1000);
        primaryStage.setHeight(700);
        primaryStage.minWidthProperty().setValue(1000);
        primaryStage.minHeightProperty().setValue(700);

        drawPane = new Pane();
        drawPane.setId("drawPane");
        drawPane.setPrefSize(1000, 800);
        drawPane.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
        drawPane.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.ALICEBLUE, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));
        root.setCenter(drawPane);

        HexGrid hexGrid = new HexGrid();

        //LEVEL OF RECURSION
        hexGrid.generate(5);

        drawWorldCanvas(hexGrid);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);

    }

    private void drawWorldCanvas(HexGrid hexGrid) {
        drawPane.getChildren().add(hexGrid.getCanvas());
    }
}
```

***************** HexGrid.java *******************

```
import javafx.geometry.Point2D;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;

import java.io.*;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class HexGrid {
    ArrayList<Point2D> _vertices = new ArrayList<>(1000);
    int _index = 0;
    FileWriter log;

    int TRIANGLE_SIDE_LENGTH = 250;

    private class TriangleFaceVertices {
        public int v1;  //these are indexes into the _vertices arrayList
        public int v2;
        public int v3;

        private TriangleFaceVertices(int v1, int v2, int v3) {
            this.v1 = v1;
            this.v2 = v2;
            this.v3 = v3;
        }
    }

    ArrayList<TriangleFaceVertices> _faces = new ArrayList<>(1000);

    public  HexGrid() {
        try {
            log = new FileWriter("log1.txt");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void generate(int recursionLevel) {
        _vertices.clear();
        _faces.clear();

        addVertices();
        addFaces();
        divideTriangles(recursionLevel);
    }

    private void divideTriangles(int recursionLevel) {
        // refine triangles
        for (int i = 0; i < recursionLevel; i++)
        {
            ArrayList<TriangleFaceVertices> faces2 = new ArrayList<>(200000);
            for (TriangleFaceVertices face: _faces)
            {
                // replace triangle by 4 triangles
                int a = getMiddlePoint(face.v1, face.v2);
                int b = getMiddlePoint(face.v2, face.v3);
                int c = getMiddlePoint(face.v3, face.v1);

                faces2.add(new TriangleFaceVertices(face.v1, a, c));
                faces2.add(new TriangleFaceVertices(face.v2, b, a));
                faces2.add(new TriangleFaceVertices(face.v3, c, b));
                faces2.add(new TriangleFaceVertices(a, b, c));
            }
            _faces = faces2;
            System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now() + " : Iteration: " + i + " - Triangle Count: " + faces2.size());
        }
    }

    private int getMiddlePoint(int v1, int v2)
    {
        Point2D point1 = _vertices.get(v1);
        Point2D point2 = _vertices.get(v2);
        Point2D middle = new Point2D(
                (point1.getX() + point2.getX()) / 2.0,
                (point1.getY() + point2.getY()) / 2.0);

        return addVertex(middle);
    }

    private int addVertex(Point2D p)
    {
        _vertices.add(p);
        return _index++;
    }

    public Canvas getCanvas() {
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(5000,2000);
        GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();

        Color landColor = Color.BEIGE;
        Color borderColor = Color.DARKKHAKI;
        gc.setFill(landColor);
        gc.setStroke(borderColor);

        gc.beginPath();
        gc.moveTo(0,0);
        gc.lineTo(2000,0);
        gc.closePath();
        //gc.stroke();

        for (TriangleFaceVertices face:_faces) {
            gc.beginPath();
            gc.moveTo(_vertices.get(face.v1).getX(), _vertices.get(face.v1).getY());
            gc.lineTo(_vertices.get(face.v2).getX(), _vertices.get(face.v2).getY());
            gc.lineTo(_vertices.get(face.v3).getX(), _vertices.get(face.v3).getY());
            gc.lineTo(_vertices.get(face.v1).getX(), _vertices.get(face.v1).getY());
            gc.closePath();
            gc.stroke();
            //gc.fill();
        }
        return canvas;
    }

    private void addFaces() {
        _faces.add(new TriangleFaceVertices(0, 2, 1)); //creates a triangle from vertices[0], [1], and [2]
        _faces.add(new TriangleFaceVertices(1, 2, 3)); 
        _faces.add(new TriangleFaceVertices(1, 3, 4));
        _faces.add(new TriangleFaceVertices(3, 5, 4));
        _faces.add(new TriangleFaceVertices(1, 7, 6));
        _faces.add(new TriangleFaceVertices(1, 4, 7));
        _faces.add(new TriangleFaceVertices(7, 4, 8));
        _faces.add(new TriangleFaceVertices(4, 9, 8));
        _faces.add(new TriangleFaceVertices(10, 7, 11));
        _faces.add(new TriangleFaceVertices(7, 8, 11));
        _faces.add(new TriangleFaceVertices(11, 8, 12));
        _faces.add(new TriangleFaceVertices(8, 13, 12));
        _faces.add(new TriangleFaceVertices(14, 11, 15));
        _faces.add(new TriangleFaceVertices(11, 12, 15));
        _faces.add(new TriangleFaceVertices(15, 12, 16));
        _faces.add(new TriangleFaceVertices(12, 17, 16));
        _faces.add(new TriangleFaceVertices(18, 15, 19));
        _faces.add(new TriangleFaceVertices(15, 16, 19));
        _faces.add(new TriangleFaceVertices(19, 16, 20));
        _faces.add(new TriangleFaceVertices(16, 21, 20));
    }

    private void addVertices(){
        float height = (float)(Math.sqrt(3.0) / 2.0) * TRIANGLE_SIDE_LENGTH;

        addVertex(new Point2D(TRIANGLE_SIDE_LENGTH / 2.0, 0));              //0
        addVertex(new Point2D(TRIANGLE_SIDE_LENGTH, height));               //1
        addVertex(new Point2D(0, height));                                  //2
        addVertex(new Point2D(TRIANGLE_SIDE_LENGTH / 2.0, height * 2.0));   //3
        addVertex(new Point2D(TRIANGLE_SIDE_LENGTH * 1.5, height * 2.0));   //4
        addVertex(new Point2D(TRIANGLE_SIDE_LENGTH, height * 3.0));         //5
        addVertex(new Point2D(TRIANGLE_SIDE_LENGTH * 1.5, 0));              //6
        addVertex(new Point2D(TRIANGLE_SIDE_LENGTH * 2.0, height));         //7
        addVertex(new Point2D(TRIANGLE_SIDE_LENGTH * 2.5, height * 2.0));   //8
        addVertex(new Point2D(TRIANGLE_SIDE_LENGTH * 2.0, height * 3.0));   //9
        addVertex(new Point2D(TRIANGLE_SIDE_LENGTH * 2.5, 0));              //10
        addVertex(new Point2D(TRIANGLE_SIDE_LENGTH * 3.0, height));         //11
        addVertex(new Point2D(TRIANGLE_SIDE_LENGTH * 3.5, height * 2.0));   //12
        addVertex(new Point2D(TRIANGLE_SIDE_LENGTH * 3.0, height * 3.0));   //13
        addVertex(new Point2D(TRIANGLE_SIDE_LENGTH * 3.5, 0));              //14
        addVertex(new Point2D(TRIANGLE_SIDE_LENGTH * 4.0, height));         //15
        addVertex(new Point2D(TRIANGLE_SIDE_LENGTH * 4.5, height * 2.0));   //16
        addVertex(new Point2D(TRIANGLE_SIDE_LENGTH * 4.0, height * 3.0));   //17
        addVertex(new Point2D(TRIANGLE_SIDE_LENGTH * 4.5, 0));              //18
        addVertex(new Point2D(TRIANGLE_SIDE_LENGTH * 5.0, height));         //19
        addVertex(new Point2D(TRIANGLE_SIDE_LENGTH * 5.5, height * 2.0));   //20
        addVertex(new Point2D(TRIANGLE_SIDE_LENGTH * 5.0, height * 3.0));   //21

    }

}
```

Comment: You did not tell us on which system and which Java version you obtained your results. I tried it on a MacBook Pro Retina with JDK 8u76 and I did not notice any strange behaviour. I just wonder why you need such a large canvas. On a retina Mac this results in a 10000x4000 pixel image. But anyway it still seems to work. I went up to level 8.

Comment: Interesting. It fails on both my Windows 10 machine (JDK 8u72) and MacBook Air (JDK 8u74) with the same (incorrect) output. Did the output have five triangular tips across the top? It should, but my incorrect version shows only three.

Comment: updated my windows machine to 8u74 and get the same results.

Comment: I have five tips at the top for all levels. Maybe I should note that I have an NVidia card  in my machine and not just the Intel graphics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does seem to have issues. You should file a bug report.

Regarding your problem: Don't use path then, instead use e. g. `strokeLine`. It's way faster anyway.

Simple example for reproduction:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    double width = 1000;
    double height = 1000;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Drawing Operations Test");
        Group root = new Group();
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(width, height);
        GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
        drawShapes(gc);
        root.getChildren().add(canvas);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void drawShapes(GraphicsContext gc) {

        double offset = 15; // <=== change this, e. g. 12

        gc.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        gc.setFill(Color.BEIGE);

        for( int x=0; x < width; x+=offset) {
            for( int y=0; y < height; y+=offset) {

                gc.setLineWidth(0.5);

                gc.beginPath();
                gc.moveTo(x, y);
                gc.lineTo(x+offset, y+offset);
                gc.closePath();

                gc.stroke();
            }

        }

    }
}
```

You should get diagonal lines.

[image]

Once you lower the offset, lines vanish.

[image]

Comment: I went down from 16 to 2 with a decrement of 2 and did not see any strange behaviour on my machine.

Comment: Tried it on a different machine now. Everything's fine there with Win7 and Java 1.8.u40. Got problems with Win7 and Java 1.8.u60 on the first machine i tried. The code in the question works also on this other machine. That's really odd.

Comment: What do the machines with problems have in common?

Comment: Thanks for your simplified example. Impressive that you could generalize my problem like that. I confirmed that I have render problems for any offset below 15. I will submit a JavaFX bug report, then start researching StrokeLine. I'm new to JavaFX and have never heard of it.

Comment: As a follow-up, converting to StrokeLine worked perfectly.  Thanks again!